# How do I fix "Windows Resource Protection could not perform the requested operation" on sfc /scannow

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, bsod, sfc

I have a problem on my Windows 8.1 PC where it displays a BSoD that says CRITICAL_PROCESS_DIED. I saw a page and it says that I have to run sfc /scannow. I went to the automatic repair and got to the Command Prompt. I started sfc /scannow and on the verification process, it gets to 100% then it said, "Windows Resource Protection could not perform the requested operation". How can I fix this?

Comment: The command you are using is confirming the Windows Recovery Environment your using doesn't have a problem.  You cannot use that tool in question while within that environment.

Answer (score 2):

When you boot into the recovery options, you must use this command:

```
sfc /SCANNOW /OFFBOOTDIR=c:\ /OFFWINDIR=c:\windows
```

to tell Windows to scan the files of the installed Windows, not the current booted WinPE.

Comment: Should I use /f and /r ?

Comment: what do you mean with /f and /r?

Comment: Sorry, I was thinking of Chkdsk. It's still not working.

Comment: Do you know how to fix CRITICAL_PROCESS_DIED?

Comment: do you use a Crucial M4 SSD? if yes, make a firmware update, one older firmware is known to cause such CRITICAL_PROCESS_DIED errors

Comment: No. I just use a regular Hard Disk Drive.

Comment: I just reinstalled Windows 8.1.